# DAX TOPN formula works on 1 PC but not on others

Tags: excel, mdx, dax, top-n

I have a calculated measure in a Power Pivot data model in excel that has so far worked for me and my co workers.

```
=FIRSTNONBLANK(SELECTCOLUMNS(TOPN(1,searchpulse_,searchpulse_[comp_impr],0,searchpulse_[sp_match_key],0),"-",searchpulse_[Most Recent Screengrab]),1)
```

All it really does is looks up a URL in the table that's ordered; works fine for me.

The weird part is that

SELECTCOLUMNS(TOPN(1,searchpulse_,searchpulse_[comp_impr],DESC,searchpulse_[sp_match_key],DESC),"-",searchpulse_[Most Recent Screengrab])

is underlined red, but when I press check formula in the measure editor, no issues are found.

When I send this spreadsheet to the client, this doesnt work, and this is the error they get

"Sorry ... the request did not work or we were unable to access the data model. Here is the error messge: MdxScript (Model) (6, 123) Unexpected value for the ORDER argument in the TOPN function. Use 0 for descending order or 1 for ascending order
"

... in french, they have a french localization if that helps.

So i changed the DESC for 0s and it still gives client the same error.

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: What excel versions do you and your client have?

Comment: @mxix - I have Excel 2016 and my client has Excel 2013